# Pandas extractall merge

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Not sure if I should fix my regex pattern, or process more with pandas.

Here's a mock setup:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

regex = r"(?P<adv>This)|(?P<noun>test)"
texts = ["This is a test", "Random stuff with no match"]
series = pd.Series(texts)
```

I want to find all matches for groups (`<adv>`, `<noun>` -- there are typically more than two). These groups are designed to be **exclusive** hence I would want to have only one row result with the captured string / NaN.

Current output: multi-index rows, only for texts that have a match

```
>>> print(series.str.extractall(regex))
          adv  noun
  match            
0 0      This   NaN
  1       NaN  test
```

Expected output: one row per input text, and aggregated matchs per group

```
          adv  noun
0        This  test
1         NaN   NaN
```

Any chance for a hand on this? Either fix the regex, or post-process with pandas.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try;

```
series.str.extractall(regex).groupby(level=0).first()

    adv  noun
0  This  test
```

Comment: Super useful. I realized that things get more complicated with more than one row and updated my question - if you can help me with that, thanks, otherwise I can also ask another question and accept this.

Comment: @Arnaud No problem, I am okay. But please tell me why are you expecting the second row.. What is the purpose , it wouldnt affect if you have multiple rows , check `pd.Series([text,text]).str.extractall(regex).groupby(level=0).first()` for example

Comment: If you use `pd.Series([text, "Random thing that doesn't match"])` then there's no second row. Because nothing is matched for the second text, but I'd still like to keep its row with `NaN` entries. Hope you see my point.

Comment: @Arnaud got it, in that case just chain a `.reindex` like `series.str.extractall(regex).groupby(level=0).first().reindex(series.index)` ?